# Empty request body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, body-parser

I generated two projects, one with create-react-app and the other with express generator.

I run the first one on `localhost:3000` and the second one on `localhost:3001`.

I'am trying to send a POST request, but I receive an empty `req.body`.

**Client side:**

```
 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();
    for (const key of Object.keys(this.state)) {
      data.append(key, this.state[key]);
    }

    const url = "http://localhost:3000/course";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: this.state
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(html => console.log(html));
  }
```

**Server side:**

`app.js`

```
app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
app.use("/course", course);
```

`router/course.js`

```
router.post("/", function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body) {
    var course = new Course(req.body);
    course
      .save()
      .then(item => {
        res.json({ course: item });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send("Unable to save to database");
      });
  }
  res.status(200).send("No data to save");
});
```

Comment: Have you added a proxy in your `package.json`? `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",`

Comment: No, why should I do that?

Comment: Shouldn't `body: this.state` be `body: data`??

Comment: I tried both, the req.body is always empty

Comment: Remove `/course` from your `url` variable (your server is `router.post("/" ...`

Comment: are you sure content-type is set to json by the client?

Comment: How does your React-app know which port you have? Since you are using `creat-react-app` and have this node backend, you need to set `"proxy": "http://localhost:XXXX"` (which is the port of your node server)

Comment: @Alejandro : I forgot to add this line`app.use("/course", course);` which is already present in my code, @Nidhin : I tried to add `let myHeaders = new Headers();myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");` but it does not work neither. @Modig : the port is in the url localhost:3000/course

Comment: Remove that from the url and add it to the package.json instead and restart your app

Comment: I added ` "proxy": "http://localhost:3000"` to the package.json of react project, kept url="/course" and restarted both apps, it's still empty, when I try whith Postman it works

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`body-parser` needs `Content-Type` header to be set to `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` in order to know that is has to parse the body

Try passing this to the headers

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/course', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```