# Getting a DTO with null fields from POST request

Tags: spring-boot, rest, post, http-headers

I wonder why I am getting a DTO object from the frontend app (Angular) with null fields,

**Front call**

```
public saveFoo(foo: Foo): Observable<Foo> {
    return this.http.post<Foo>(API_ROOT_URL + "/foos/", foo})
}
```

**Back handeling**

```
@PostMapping("/foos/")
public ResponseEntity<FooDto> createFoo(@RequestBody FooDto fooDto) {
   return ResponseEntity.ok(FooService.saveFoo(FooDto));
}
```

I tried adding some json type headers (as suggested here [Empty request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889868/empty-request-body/47891031)) but in vain :

```
{
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue : my front DTO fields are just wrong and dont match with the RequestBody Object type.

My IDE (IntelliJ) adds automatiquely an underscore "_" at the beginning of every field after generating the getters and setters:

```
export class FooClass{

  private _foo: string;

  get foo(): string {
    return this._foo;
  }

  set foo(value: string) {
    this._foo= value;
  }
}
```